# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. Как исправить

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть JavaScript-кoд.

```
$("[data-scroll]").on("click", function(Event) {
    Event.preventDefault();
    let ElementId = $(this).data('scroll');
    let elementOffset = $(ElementId).offset().top;

    console.log(elementOffset);
});
```

И в ней выдаёт ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.
Как ёё исправить?

Comment: `console.log("ElementId =", ElementId);` - что выводит в консоль? `let elementOffset = $("#" + ElementId).offset().top;`

Comment: а заче, если сверху он его находит `let ElementId = $(this).data('scroll');`. Может нужно изменить `$(ElementId).offset().top;` на `ElementId.offset().top;`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Я думаю, надо так, как я написал :). Как Вы предлагаете работать не будет, потому что `ElementId` это строка.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это пока чистая телепатия.

Comment: однозначно можно сказать, что у `$(ElementId)` нет свойства `offset()`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Правильно сказать: вызов метода `$(ElementId).offset()` вернул `undefined`. Например, потому что выборка `$(ElementId)` - пустая.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь определить положение не самого элемента, а его атрибута `data`.

Для того, чтобы определить положение самого элемента стоит задать `$(this).offset().top;`, где `$(this)` - *то на что* кликнули.

```js
$("[data-scroll]").on("click", function(Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let ElementId = $(this).data('scroll');
  let elementOffset = $(this).offset().top;

  console.log(elementOffset);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>


<a href="#" data-scroll="scroll">
    data-scroll
  </a>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё получилось))